# About the use of Phaser3.60 and Tweens Animation

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

We would like to get the coordinates and angles of multiple objects from a json file and create a playback of around 30,000~50,000 animations.
Is PhaserJS(3.60) suitable for this case?
If suitable, is it correct to use Tweens?

When I run Seek() in Phaser 3.60, the tween animation starts late and the object coordinates and rotation angle are wrong.

Comment: About the performance with 30,000 - 50,000 I can't really say I would recomend testing it, but since [this official demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/40000-world-bodies) runs with about 40,000 physics objects, so I asume it should be possible _(**warning:** so many object might cause performance issue, and might not work well on slow computers)_. Do you have a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the late start and the wrong rotation?

Comment: Is your question solved? Or is it still open? If it is open can you shatr some more details to your problem?

Comment: Still under investigation.